# Cancelation fee on a unsuccessfully booked room

Tags: bookings, cancellations

In April we booked a Hotel for our vacation in Greece in June. The booking took place on the hotel's website. We decided to pay immediately and not have the classical "make a reservation that you can cancel until a week ahead"-type of booking. That way we could save a few bucks.

After having submitted the form, the Hotel approached us via mail,the payment did not work out. They asked us to send them our credit card information in plain text. I was somewhat reluctant, since this is not a secure way of transferring sensitive data. So I asked them whether they could cancel the booking and we just try it once more with another credit card via the website. They refused. So we sent them the credit card data via mail. They still could not book (we did not receive any notification from our bank about some sort of denied request). So we sent them my girlfriend's credit card information. No response, upon  request they claim the booking was once more unsuccessful.

Next they ask us to transfer money via bank deposit. We refuse since we lose some control over the process, apart from hefty fees for international bank transfers. And somewhat everything looks very fishy and untrustworthy to me.

That's why we asked them now to cancel the booking altogether. They want to charge us a cancelation fee. I find this an absolute disgrace.

Am I wrong or are they wrong? The hotel is olive green in Crete BTW.

Comment: How would they charge you the cancellation fee if all payments you sent really failed?

Comment: exactly my latest response..

Comment: @bogardpd: Theoretically they could sue you in court.

Comment: @AnatraIlDuck Are you US-based? If yes, did you inform your bank that charges from abroad are expected? It may be that both you and your SO have charges from abroad on your cards disabled, in which case it would not be the hotel's fault that the charge could be made. Also, did you *call* your bank to check if charging the card has been tried? The online banking systems do not always show all requests, and your bank's customer service center may see more details.

Comment: I would argue that since you chose the option to pay the full amount upfront, you have not yet actually made a reservation, since this transaction has not completed (and there is therefore nothing to cancel and no fee to pay).

Comment: From their point of view, you presented them invalid credit card data, when confronted send another fake credit card data, and when required to use the most reliable payment method, you refused. This sounds cheesy!

Comment: @bogardpd saying that to them would make them sure you wasn't going to pay from beginning...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hotel has very good reviews on Tripadvisor and as long as you booked it on their actual website (http://www.olivegreenhotel.com/) its unlikely to be a scam, although it sure looks like one.

Stating the obvious: if they weren't able to charge you for the room, I don't see how they can charge you for a cancellation. I'd do the following:

1. write a back a polite letter  "unfortunately you have not been been
   able to process our payments even after three different options were
   given. We therefore need to cancel the reservation and cancellation
   fees do not apply".
2. Keep a copy of that letter.
3. If a charge pops up on your credit card, dispute the charge with
   your credit card issuer and send them a copy of the the letter as
   proof.

Comment: Hilmar - Writing a letter and telling the hotel that they can't charge their cancellation fee does not negate the contract and their right to charge a cancellation fee.

Comment: @Tom . Agreed. It's a purely defensive measure. In case of conflict having the letter is better than not having one. What alternatives would you suggest ?

Answer (score 4):

Do not pay them anything. I doubt that they will try to charge you because they know it's their fault that you cancelled.

Threatening them that you will write your story (along with a low rate review) in Tripadvisor or booking.com might convince them to cancel your booking right away.

Comment: The OP has failed to pay for reservation. How it is hotel's fault?

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo It is the hotel's fault not to recognize that it is not the client's fault if the OP has any problems. They know that the client did anything they could in order to make the payment possible and since the OP or anything else (but not the client) failed, they should cancel the reservation without any obstacles. What they are doing is extremely unprofessional.

Comment: No, it's not. They didn't do anything, because they refused to do bank transfer, which is the most logical thing in such circumstances. He had also probably no way to check why the card was blocked. It's possible that giving overcharged prepaid card data to force cancelling booking is a common trick in that area.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo The hotel asked for credit card details in plain text. I would have stopped any interaction with them at this point.

Comment: Although it's highly unprofessional, it doesn't change the fact, you're oblidged to pay. It's just like you would leave restaurant without paying because the waiter's uniform was dirty.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo You are obliged to pay if you have used the hotel's services. In this case no services were used.

Comment: is there such a clause in Greek law? because in other EU countries (Germany for example) there's something like the obligation to pay after ordering something (in e-shops mostly).

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo They did try to pay.

Comment: sorry, if you suggest that trying to pay equals paying, than your whole answer is based on pure speculation and is potentially dangerous to OP

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo I won't continue this discussion. I'm certain that you know what my point is.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo If I go to McDonalds, place and order, but don't pay, they won't serve me the food.  The terms of the reservation are prepaid; the hotel should not be creating a reservation until AFTER payment is provided.  If there's no reservation until after a payment is made, there should be no cancelation fee as a reservation never existed.  A sit down restaurant serves you the food BEFORE you pay.  That's a huge difference.